# Unable to loop through array field ES 6.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing a problem in ElasticSearch 6.1  that I cannot solve and I don't know why. I have read the docs several times and maybe I'm missing something.

I have a scripted query that needs to do some calculation before decides if a record is available or not.

Here is the following script:
https://gist.github.com/dunice/a3a8a431140ec004fdc6969f77356fdf

What I'm doing is trying to loop though an array field with the following source:

```
  "unavailability": [
    {
      "starts_at": "2018-11-27T18:00:00+00:00",
      "local_ends_at": "2018-11-27T15:04:00",
      "local_starts_at": "2018-11-27T13:00:00",
      "ends_at": "2018-11-27T20:04:00+00:00"
    },
    {
      "starts_at": "2018-12-04T18:00:00+00:00",
      "local_ends_at": "2018-12-04T15:04:00",
      "local_starts_at": "2018-12-04T13:00:00",
      "ends_at": "2018-12-04T20:04:00+00:00"
    },
  ]
```

When the script is executed it throws the error: **No field found for [unavailability] in mapping with types [aircraft]**

Is there any clue to make it work?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Query:
https://gist.github.com/dunice/3ccd7d83ca6ddaa63c11013b84e659aa

**UPDATE 2**

Mapping:
https://gist.github.com/dunice/f8caee114bbd917115a21b8b9175a439

Data example:
https://gist.github.com/dunice/8ad0602bc282b4ca19bce8ae849117ad

Comment: There is no field `unavailability` in your mapping, right?

Comment: @Val Right. I tried your solution before and it throws **Variable [_source] is not defined.**

Comment: Yeah depending on your version of ES, can you try `ctx._source` or `params._source` as well?

Comment: @Val 

ctx throws **Variable [ctx] is not defined.**
params throws **
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": null
          }**

Comment: @Val I'm using ES 6.1 with docker

docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.2

Comment: What about `params._source`?

Comment: Neither... it throws a **null_pointer_exception**

https://gist.github.com/dunice/6000ce70a11d9e1981bad09ccac32f1c

Comment: Is it possible that certain documents don't have the `unavailability` field?

Comment: No. I'm forcing to add the `unavailability` field.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that in your mapping you create an index named `local_aircraft_company` but in your search you're querying `local_aircraft`. Might that be the culprit? Also the type names don't match, i.e. `aircraft_company` in the mapping vs `aircraft` in the query.

Comment: Oh... No. I renamed the `local_aircraft_company` to `local_aircraft` just for simplicity on the questioning process. Please consider the index name and query the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my use-case in a different approach.

Instead having a field as array of object like `unavailability` was I decided to create two fields as array of datetime:
`unavailable_from`
`unavailable_to`

My script walks through the first field then checks the second with the same position.

**UPDATE**

The direct access to `_source` is disabled by default:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17558

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an array present in the source document via doc_values (i.e. `doc`). You need to directly access the source document via the `_source` variable instead, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < params._source['unavailability'].length; i++) {
```

Note that depending on your ES version, you might want to try `ctx._source` or just `_source` instead of `params._source`

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17558) indeed prevents source access within script queries.